# Implementing logic in a different way

Tags: java, algorithm, functional-programming

I need to write a function which will do the following functionalities

I would get a string and a array as input parameters

The string would be like one of the following for example

```
catalog 
level1Cats
level2Cats
```

The String array would be containing the data for the strings mentioned above for example

```
catalog:("12605")

level1Cats:("12605_For the Home") OR level1Cats:("12605_Clothing")

level2Cats:("12605_For the Home_Appliances")
```

Now if the String is catalog and the array is the one mentioned above then the output should be `12605`.

If its is `level1Cats` then the output should be an array of the following strings

```
12605_For the Home 
12605_Clothing
```

I wrote the following code to implement the above mentioned logic It's doing the functionality without a flaw, Can i implement the same in a different and a more efficient way?

```
public static String[] parseFQ(String fqField, String fqs[]) {

    List<String> prefixes = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(fqField != null && fqField.length() > 0
            && fqs != null && fqs.length > 0) {

        //Get the fq which starts with given field name.
        for(String fq : fqs) {
            if(fq.startsWith(fqField)) {
                fqField = fq;
                break;
            }
        }

        boolean parsed = false;
        while(!parsed) {
            int quoteStart = fqField.indexOf("\"");
            int quoteEnd = (quoteStart >= 0) ? fqField.indexOf("\"", quoteStart+1) : -1;
            if(quoteEnd > 0) {
                prefixes.add(fqField.substring(quoteStart+1, quoteEnd));
                fqField = fqField.substring(quoteEnd+1, fqField.length());
            } else {
                parsed = true;
            }               
        }
    }
    //Return the prefixes array
    return prefixes.toArray(new String[]{});
}
```

Comment: just curiosity, your string contains label and actual value, right? why you can put them into ie map?

Comment: How about using JSON.
{
    name: "12605",
    children: [{
        name: "For the Home",
        children: [{
            name: "Appliances"
        }]
    }, {
        name: "Clothing"
    }]
}

Answer (score 2):

Below code is more readable and no need of using our logic around single quotes.

```
String[] w = fqField.split("\"");
for (int i = 1; i < w.length; i+=2) {
    prefixes.add(w[i]);
}
```